# Why is value "External_links" and not items scraped from website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

My code is below, but why does the `brand` value output `External_links` instead of the list of items that I have pulled.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq


my_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
headline = page_soup.findAll("span",{"class":"mw-headline"})

for item in headline:
    brand = item["id"] # Outputs "External_links"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop you are iterating over each of the headlines in the page and then assigning the headline value to the variable `brand`. Once the loop has finished, the value of `brand` will be the last headline ("External_links").

If you modify your code to print out the value for each headline, you will see that you are getting the values that you're looking for.

```
>>> for item in headline:
...    print(item["id"])
...
Plot
Early_years
Voldemort_returns
Supplementary_works
Harry_Potter_and_the_Cursed_Child
In-universe_books
Pottermore_website
Structure_and_genre
Themes
Origins
Publishing_history
Translations
Completion_of_the_series
Cover_art
Achievements
Cultural_impact
Commercial_success
Awards,_honours,_and_recognition
Reception
Literary_criticism
Social_impact
Controversies
Adaptations
Films
Spin-off_prequels
Games
Audiobooks
Stage_production
Attractions
The_Wizarding_World_of_Harry_Potter
The_Making_of_Harry_Potter
References
Further_reading
External_links
```

Comment: but I need to assign this to a variable so I can export to csv, is this possible?

Comment: You could create a list and then add each heading to the list, then write the contents of the list to file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `brand` variable needs to be a list, for example the code could look like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from pprint import pprint

my_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter'
with uReq(my_url) as uClient:
    page_html = uClient.read()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "xml")

brand = []
for item in page_soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'mw-headline'}):
    brand.append(item["id"])

pprint(brand)
```

Prints:

```
['Plot',
 'Early_years',
 'Voldemort_returns',
 'Supplementary_works',
 'Harry_Potter_and_the_Cursed_Child',
 'In-universe_books',
 'Pottermore_website',
 'Structure_and_genre',
 'Themes',
 'Origins',
 'Publishing_history',
 'Translations',
 'Completion_of_the_series',
 'Cover_art',
 'Achievements',
 'Cultural_impact',
 'Commercial_success',
 'Awards,_honours,_and_recognition',
 'Reception',
 'Literary_criticism',
 'Social_impact',
 'Controversies',
 'Adaptations',
 'Films',
 'Spin-off_prequels',
 'Games',
 'Audiobooks',
 'Stage_production',
 'Attractions',
 'The_Wizarding_World_of_Harry_Potter',
 'The_Making_of_Harry_Potter',
 'References',
 'Further_reading',
 'External_links']
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieving the same using list comprehension:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
items = [item.get('id') for item in soup.find_all('span',class_='mw-headline')]
pprint(items)
```